# Generate Diagram From Scenario

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Quick question: I'm using EA version 10 and try to generate a sequence diagram from scenario using c#

```
GenerateDiagramFromScenario(usecase.ElementGUID,EnumScenarioDiagramType.sdSequence, 0);
```

But it throws a `NotImplementedException`
So my question is: Can I do that with my actual version of EA or do I have to update to EA 11 or 12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the help since (at least) 9.3. So: report a bug. Looks like a method that's not widely used.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas
Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: I guess not, except doing it manually. There are quite some functions in the API which are very rarely used. Unfortunately, as it seems, you have discovered one of them.